# Check not log user has almost read my video without cookie and account (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, vue.js

**Detect a user who has already followed my video or already clicked on a button without using cookies. (Cookies can be deleted from the browser.) Is there a way? much like the youtube view number system**

Comment: What's your definition of 'user'? Is it the same browser? Same IP? Same computer? Same human in front of it? There's no ethical and reliable way to do this without user permission besides cookies/localstorage.

Comment: so no other ways beside use cookies and localstorage? I want to make same thing as youtube number of video view. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You can research "browser fingerprinting" topic as additional way to identify users (more specifically, their PCs and browsers), but cookies/LS is the only appropriate way to do this and usually it's enough. If users don't want to be identified by a website, they are allowed to clear cookies. For anything that is more sensitive to unfair user activity, you need auth and antibot countermeasures.

Comment: I'm unaware how YT view count works but I suspect they have a sophisticated system against view boosts that uses fingerprinting but isn't limited to user identification. if you want to know how YT views work, try to ask at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ , then you can use it for your own implementation if needed.

Comment: thanks i will check it. i have now a clear idea of what to do.